# SQL utl_raw.cast_to_raw XML Delimiter for single quotes

Tags: sql, xml, delimiter

I am trying to insert some XML data into a blob column using utl_raw.cas_to_raw.

But my XML contains a single quote (as part of a query), which prevents me from inserting the row to XML.

The query is like this:

```
INSERT INTO ABCD 
VALUES (utl_raw.cast_to_raw('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><resource name="ID" ><value Type="multiple" query="select role_no, name from mytable where name='A'"/></resource>'),'C2','C3');
```

The part- **name='A'** is causing issue. Please help me with this.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can escape quotes (`'`) with 2 single quotes ( `''`) or backslash quote (`\'`)

Comment: Thanks juergen
( '' ) did the job.
:)